# Oracle update multiple columns in multiple tables

Tags: oracle

Need a bit of help on a query for Oracle. Basically I would like to put together a query that updates a number of columns to replace actual data with test data. To do this we need to do things like change project codes in two tables, but the references must match, so for example I'm looking to do...

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2 
SET t1.project_ref = concat('projectRef-',rownum), 
    t2.project_ref = t1.project_ref 
WHERE t1.project_ref = t2.project_ref and t1.project_client = XYZ
```

This would change t1.project_ref and t2.project_ref to something like 'projectRef-1' for client XYZ.

Any ideas?

Regards

KS

Comment: :You need two different update statements for that

Comment: Hmmmm, going to be awkward if I have 1,279 projects reference numbers, I update in one table, then have to go through and do it in the second. How will I know which relates to which. Kind of hoping Oracle could do something clever here (it costs enough, I'd like it to earn it's fees :-D )

Answer (score 4):

Generally updates on joins are possible in Oracle.

This is the syntax:
update (select T1.* from T1, T2 where .. ) set ...

They require a join condition between T1 and T2, and a unique index on the join column in T2 to assure that the select returns at most one column per row in T1.
Unfortunately for you there is another limitation that says, that only columns in one of the tables can be updated (T1 here).

So you need an intermediate table where you insert the changeset of project_ref to new-project_ref and then use this table to update T1 and T2 separately.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're going to have to build a translation table.  Something like:

```
project_test_data
-----------------
real_project_ref varchar2(30)
test_project_ref varchar2(30)
```

Then write update statements substituting the test version for the real version in the relevant tables.

Note that if you have defined foreign key relationships on these columns you will need to disable them, or at least make them deferrable and deferred.  This is one reason to avoid using meaningful data as primary keys.